# Android Bitmap Factory not picking up resized image

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I had an image which was originally 854 by 190 which I resized using GIMP to 567 by 120. When i click the image it shows these dimensions so all looks good ( I also tried the same process with Paint).

I load the image through java by calling:

Bitmap test = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launch);

However when i call test.getWidth() it is still returning the original 854, I have rebuilt, refreshed, readded under a different name no matter what I do it is always returns this width instead of the new 567.

Any ideas?
thanks L.

Answer (score 0):

decodeRecource reads file as it is and resize using scale factor. you have probably hdpi-screen device/emulator and don't have this drawable in drawable-hdpi, so android scales up by factor 1.5. Android tries to create same DPI size bitmap, not pixel-oriented, e.g. drawable is in drawable/ folder, not in drawable-xxx/ where xx is like below

xxhdpi: 3.0 xhdpi: 2.0 hdpi: 1.5 mdpi: 1.0 (baseline) ldpi: 0.75, more in documentation ang Goole, search for "scale factor android"

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot about this. I still have a problem though so my image is a 12 frame animation so it should do width/12 to get the width of each frame, however now it is scaled it getting 1.25 frames. Almost as if its taking the scaled width and cutting this width out of the normal image?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the folder contains resources that are not being updated, delete this folder:

C: \ android \ workspace \ garagecoders \ tecnoblinds \ tecnoblinds \ bin \ res \ crunch

If you use diferent drawable folders...

use drawable-nodpi